# Can an ovulation calculator increase your likelihood of getting pregnant?

Tags: pregnancy, fertility, human-reproduction

An ovulation calculator is something that apears on most pregnancy and baby sites on the internet. Searching for the term "ovulation calculator" on Google produces over 2 million results.

This "tool" is supposed to indicate when during a woman's menstrual cycle is the best time to try for a baby as there is supposedly a greater chance that you will be successful in this period.

Is there any evidence to suggest that using a calendar will increase the chance of a woman being pregnant as opposed to using common sense and logic?

Comment: Side note: The number of Google hits a search topic gets has nothing to do with its importance or value.  Please see [9,000 Google hits can't be wrong - or can they?](http://www.csmonitor.com/2004/0227/p09s01-coop.html).

Comment: @Kyralessa - I don't see where I matched prevalance to importance or value? My point was to go and see for yourself, rather than pointing to a specific example because they are so prevelant. That's why the first two sentences are together. Also, anyone who has had a baby would know that they are important enough that everyone sticks them on their site.

Comment: If common sense and logic suggest to use a calendar, there is no opposition.

Comment: Calculator or calendar?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order for conception to occur, there has to be an egg (or ova) present for the sperm to fertilize, where the '**average**' woman will ovulate around [day 14](http://www.epigee.org/guide/reproduction.html) (from the first day of the last menstrual period).

Of course, not every woman is average.  Because the human ova is [viable](http://www.fertilityfriend.com/Faqs/The-Fertile-Window---Scientific-Literature-Review.html) for a short period (~24 hours), knowing the right 'window' of time is helpful if you wish to become pregnant. The calendar method can (and often is) used in conjunction with basal body temperature measurements and the examination of mucus, and is based upon [statistical analysis](http://www-3.unipv.it/dipstea/workingpapers/24.pdf) studies. Some calendars will show a fertility window for the next 3 months, allowing for more 'planning' of bedroom fun. (Vacation, honeymoon, etc)

I'll be honest, it's much easier for me to plunk down my information on a calendar, hit "ENTER" and get a nifty calendar in front of me for the next 3 months, than to pull out my desk calendar, find the first day of my last menstrual period, then count forward to when my next should arrive, then backwards again 14 days, then back another 4 days, etc....and to do that for the next three months?  Call me lazy, I don't mind.

Common sense (and logic) says that if you want to get pregnant, you need to have sex.  However, work, school, kids, and life in general can sometimes distract you - and having a calendar can give that extra 'nudge' in the right direction.  (wink wink, say no more).

Is using the calendar the [best option](http://journals.lww.com/greenjournal/Abstract/2002/12000/Timing_Intercourse_to_Achieve_Pregnancy__Current.27.aspx)?  No, charting BBT and purchasing an ovulation test are much more precise; however they aren't free - while an online calendar is. There are also women who aren't thrilled about taking and charting their [temperature daily](http://www.pregnancy.org/article/how-chart-your-basal-body-temperature).

There are also women who utilize it for *avoiding* pregnancy - given the short lifespan of the ova, they know which days to avoid unprotected sex - this was called the [rhythm method](http://www.bmj.com/content/307/6906/723.abstract) Current [natural family](http://www.fertstert.org/article/S0015-0282%2899%2900365-9/abstract) planning methods utilize a similar [approach](http://www.contraceptionjournal.org/article/S0010-7824%2802%2900288-3/abstract), which avoids intercourse during the most fertile phase.

ETA: An overview of [high vs low tech](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6W6R-4F60C4B-9&_user=641802&_coverDate=01/31/2005&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=gateway&_origin=gateway&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1748029174&_rerunOrigin=scholar.google&_acct=C000034418&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=641802&md5=30a517535b201257ce64c0f5936e5d9c&searchtype=a) contraception

Comment: The article behind the last link endorses the rhythm method. This is highly misleading, since **the rhythm method doesn’t work**: even though the ovum is only viable for ~24h, sperm survives in the uterus much longer. Furthermore, reliably anticipating ovulation is much harder in practice than in theory. [Failure rates for this method are unacceptably](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhythm_method#Failure_rate) high compared to other methods of contraception, so this is *not* a reliable contraceptive measure under usual circumstances.

Comment: I never said it was a reliable method of birth control; merely that some women opt to use it.

Comment: I am aware of that. But since your mention of the method was neutral and the only link you’re giving explicitly endorses the method this is misleading for uninformed readers. The 1993 article was heavily criticised in the scientific community because its conclusion is based on wrong information and flawed methodology and doesn’t stand up to scrutiny.

Comment: I'll edit to add in other similar results.

Comment: @Konrad - as the old joke states, "what do you call people who practice rhythm method of Birth Control? ... Parents".

Comment: As a sperm donor I have helped numerous people to get pregnant without having sex, so I deny your common sense :P  As a sperm donor I can also say from personal experience that these calendar apps are not perfect, but allot better then nothing for planning sperm donations, but that's just anecdotal.

Comment: FWIW, most of the modern NFP methods incorporate BBT or cervical mucous checks rather than relying on just dates. It is technically speaking a similar approach since it does depend on understanding the body's natural cycles so as to know when the woman is fertile, but the current statement is a bit like saying that modern pilots, much like their predecessors who relied on paper charts and compasses, use a similar approach today when flying planes of pointing their places toward their destination and not the ground. :-D